# JAXB annotations for java classes

Tags: java, jaxb

I have class Foo which I have annotated with `@XmlRootElement` and have Attribute of same type Foo which is a list as follows, also I have getter/setter for that list. The interface just has that getter and setter declaration.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "foo")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class FooImpl implements Foo{

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "secondaryFooList")
    @XmlElement(name = "secondaryFoo", type = FooImpl.class)
    private List<Foo> secondaryFooList;

}
```

When I write unit test and provide secondaryFooList by creating new Foo object and add to list, then set that in Foo object, the marshalling to xml fails with error

> com.sun.istack.SAXException2: A cycle is detected in the object graph.
>   This will cause infinitely deep XML.

I see why it is cyclic but don't know how to fix it.

Thanks,